# getIntent().getExtras() not returning as null even after app restart

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following intent in my `onMessageReceived`. This the only time I create an intent in my app. For some reason `getIntent().getExtras()` never returns null even after I close the app down and restart it without receiving any notifications. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    String channelId = "Default";
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());

    if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
        String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");
        intent.putExtra("url",url);

        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you using local broadcastmanager for?

Comment: I’m trying to get the url payload of a notification to my web view to load a url. I’m pretty sure I’m doing it the hard way though

Comment: I think you won't require local broadcast manager for that.. as you are already passing the url in your intent..did you try removing local broadcast manager and passing url only through intent??

Comment: Is intent.putextra enough to add it to the intent? I don’t have my pc with me so I will have to try tomorrow

Comment: yes it's enough..and when you go to your main activity you can get the data using getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: I will check it out tomorrow thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186335/discussion-between-amit-jangid-and-cesar-bielich).